# What is the correct way to include one js file in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

The following JavaScript code works:

```js
let Color = require('color');

class Example {
    its_not_easy_being_green() {
        return Color('green');
    }
}

test('It is not easy being green', () => {
    expect(new Example().its_not_easy_being_green()).toBeDefined();
})
```

and `npx jest` gets me a greenbar.

```
$ npx jest
 PASS  test/example.spec.js
  ✓ It is not easy being green (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.351 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

However, any time I try to separate the class from the test I get various errors:

The most common is one about not being permitted to use import outside a module.

Or that `Example` is not a constructor.

What I am trying to do is move everything that isn't the three line test *out* of the JavaScript file that I've posted above.

If this were Java, I'd move that stuff into a separate `.java` file and then `import` that file in my test.

If this were C there would be a linker and `#include` involved.

What I've tried is to create an `Example.js` file:

```js
let Color = require('color');

class Example {
    its_not_easy_being_green() {
        return Color('green');
    }
}
```

and then `require` it in the test:

```
let Example = require('Example.js')

test('It is not easy being green', () => {
    expect(new Example().its_not_easy_being_green()).toBeDefined();
})
```

But that gets me a complaint about `Example` not being a constructor, which, I suppose is true. It is a class, which presumably has a pretty inert default constructor of some kind.

I've also tried replacing the `require` with an `import`:

```
import('Example.js')

test('It is not easy being green', () => {
    expect(new Example().its_not_easy_being_green()).toBeDefined();
})
```

But that gets complaints about not being permitted to use `import` outside a module.

Is it possible to separate the jest test from the code being tested in JavaScript?

Comment: So, you showed us the code that works.  You did not show us the code you have problems with.  If you want help, you will need to describe a specific problem you have and show us the code you were using when you had that problem and be sure to describe what you're trying to accomplish.  On the surface, it sounds like you don't understand how to properly create and/or use modules in nodejs, but that's just a guess based on a few words in your question.  People can only supply an answer when you describe a very specific problem and show the code you have that had that problem.

Comment: If you're getting a complaint about `Example` not being a constructor, then you're apparently not exporting that constructor properly in `example.js`. Please show us the code for that file too.

Comment: There is no `#include` in Javascript - it uses a module system instead where you export things you want to share. Best to learn the tools the language offers rather than trying to force it to do something the way a different language does things. Also, note there are two types of modules in nodejs, `CommonJS` modules that use `require()` and `module.exports` and `ESM` modules that use `import` and `export`. Your project appears to be set up for `CommonJS` so that's what you would use unless you want to configure the project to be an ESM module project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `#include` in Javascript - it uses a module system instead where you `export` things you want to share.

It is best to learn the tools the language offers rather than trying to force it to do something the way a different language does things.

Also, note there are two types of modules in nodejs, CommonJS modules that use `require()` and `module.exports` and ESM modules that use `import` and `export`. Your project appears to be set up for CommonJS so that's what you would use unless you want to configure the project to be an ESM module project and then use the ESM rules for importing and exporting.

For a CommonJS project:

```
const Color = require('color');

class Example {
    its_not_easy_being_green() {
        return Color('green');
    }
}

module.exports.Example = Example;
```

Then, in your main file:

```
const { Example } = require('./Example.js')

test('It is not easy being green', () => {
    expect(new Example().its_not_easy_being_green()).toBeDefined();
});
```

---

FYI, `require(someModule)` gets you whatever `module.exports` was.  If you assign something directly to `module.exports` such as:

```
// in color.js

module.exports = function Color() {
     // do something here
}
```

Then, you would use that like this:

```
const Color = require('color');
```

---

But, if you just add a property to the `module.exports` object such as this:

```
// in Example.js
const Color = require('color');

class Example {
    its_not_easy_being_green() {
        return Color('green');
    }
}

module.exports.Example = Example;
```

Then you must get the `.Example` property off the exported object in any of these ways:

```
const { Example } = require('./Example.js');

const Example = require('./Example.js').Example;

const exampleExports = require('./Example.js');
const Example = exampleExports.Example;
```

Note, the brackets in the syntax:

```
const { Example } = require('./Example.js');
```

is called "object destructuring" and is a shortcut syntax.

The color.js method above is done when there's only one main export from the module so rather than exporting an object, you export the function directly.

The example.js method above is done when you have more than one main export from the module (or you want to retain the flexibility to have more than one top-level export in the future) like this:

```
// in Example.js
const Color = require('color');

class Example {
    its_not_easy_being_green() {
        return Color('green');
    }
}

class SubExample extends Example {
    its_not_easy_being_red() {
        return Color('red');
    }
} 

// multiple exports
module.exports.Example = Example;
module.exports.SubExample = SubExample;
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the tools that JS offers. I was just using other languages to express what I was trying to achieve.

The code you present here uses `const Color = require('color');` and `const { Example } = require('./Example.js')`. Can you explain why the braces are necessary around `Example` but not around `Color`?

Also, when is it appropriate to use ESM modules and when CommonJS modules?

Comment: @spierepf - See what I added to the end of my answer as additional explanation.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thanks so much!

Comment: @spierepf - Your welcome.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to "accept" it.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure here.